# Existence of a specific type of ultrafilter

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, filters

Does there exist an ultrafilter $\omega$ on $N$ with the following property:

$\forall A \in \omega$ we have that $kA \in \omega$ for a fixed $k \in N$. Where $kA = \{ka : a \in A\}$.

I do not believe there is such an ultrafilter, but could not immediately see why one does not exist. An answer that shows there is one would be highly welcomed. Thanks for the any help.

Comment: By fixed, do you mean $k$ doesn't depend on $A$? Also, I suppose you want $k>1$?

Comment: Yes k is independent of A, and k > 1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that $k>1$, and that you do not care about the principal ultrafilter generated by $\{0\}$, there are no such ultrafilters: Fix $k>1$, and consider an ultrafilter $\mathcal U$ on $\mathbb N$ as described. Note that $\mathcal U$ is non-principal (else $\mathcal U$ contains a singleton $\{s\}$, which is disjoint from $\{ks\}$ unless $s=0$, which we are explicitly excluding).

Given $A\in\mathcal U$, we may assume that $0\notin A$ since $\mathcal U$ is non-principal. Now let $A_E$ be the subset of $A$ consisting of those elements of $A$ such that the largest power of $k$ dividing them is even, and let $A_O=A\setminus A_E$. Precisely one of these two sets, call it $B$, is in $\mathcal U$. Now note that $kB$ is disjoint from $B$, and we are done.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that I was only concerned with non-principal ultrafilters.

Comment: (It was funny, I thought about mentioning it, and did not, because it seemed silly. But then somebody pointed out that there is no largest power of $k$ dividing $0$, which led to the even sillier first paragraph.)